# Display a group of list items that are associated with a record in another list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, lookup-column

For the project I'm working on, I've been tasked with creating a project and task tracking SharePoint site for my team. I've created lists and views for tracking the **tasks**, **projects**, and timelines (a.k.a. **sprints**), and I'm looking for a way to display each sprint, and underneath each sprint, every task that was completed in said sprint.

The sprint list has 3 fields: ID, Start Date, and End Date. The task list has several fields; among them is a 'Completed Sprint #' field. This field is a lookup field of sprint.ID.

Example output:

```
Sprint 1 - 7/21/2015 to 8/3/2015
    ○ Some information of a task completed in this sprint
    ○ Some information of a task completed in this sprint
Sprint 2 - 8/4/2015 to 8/17/2015
    ○ Some information of a task completed in this sprint
Sprint 3 - 8/18/2015 to 9/1/2015
    ○ Some information of a task completed in this sprint
```

Thanks for any help!

Bonus: Is there a way to create a button (plus or minus sign) to the left of each sprint to collapse or expand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already linked the tasks with sprint ID in Task List, Now you are looking for a way to display each sprint, and underneath each sprint, every task that was completed. So

- in the Sprint ID lookup field, you have options to select the fields related to sprint > try to select the fields that you need to show with its related tasks like Spring Name, Start Date , End Date.
- in Task list try to create a new view that grouped by sprint ID to collapse or expand its related tasks!

Hope you got my point.